# Change datasource on button click in Winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview (**dataGridView1**) pulling information out of a mdb datasource called rentBindingSource, how can I pull information out of hireBindingSource on a button click i.e.

```
    private void viewHire_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // refresh datagrid view to load stuff from hireBindingSource
    }
```

Comment: the `information` is too general, you have to understand what the info structure is and pull it.

Comment: What details do you need - I can update the question to include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private void viewHire_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = hireBindingSource;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - I get the following error messages: `'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` and `'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataSourceID' and no extension method 'DataSourceID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: I have updated my answer. `DataGrid`s don't have `DataBind()` event and you don't need that. Please tell if this is working.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly - this is the error I get now `'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataSourceID' and no extension method 'DataSourceID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Updated. What type is `hireBindingSource` of? It must be of type `BindingSource`.

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: Did you try the solution? You can check that at the declaration of `hireBindingSource` or in Visual Studio you can just hover the mouse pointer over the variable and it will show you it's datatype.